# Grocery crud - How to change fields values on view/read

Tags: view, grocery-crud

Can someone help me please ?

```
if ($crud->columns['NAME'] == '')
{
    $crud->columns['NAME'] = "Anonymous";
}
```

How can I do it the right way ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to give more information about your case, for example, field type.

From Grocery Crud documentation:

http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/field_type#dropdown-field

If you have a dropdown field named 'status', you can set values like this:

```
$crud->field_type('status','dropdown',
        array('1' => 'active', '2' => 'private','3' => 'spam' , '4' => 'deleted'));
```

You will have the values set for view/read and edit.